# Adding text files in few folders

Tags: python, helper

Hello I have to create a program that will create a txt file with 2 lines, in folders created by my  previous program but i cannot do it. Then i have to write a programme that will read all lines from txt files.

Here i send how my programme 1 look like, second's ss is added

1

```
import os
path ='C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\l5\\'
os.chdir(path)
for i in range (1,6):
    NewFolder='Folder'+str(i)
    os.makedirs(NewFolder)
```

I would like to get a programme wchich will add a txt file to all created folders

Comment: You already know how to create the folder name.  Now you just need to open a file in that folder.  Show us what you've tried.

Comment: i've tred multiple times, but it's not working, i was creating simple loops or using open function but still didnt get a result

Comment: Do one at a time first.  `f = open('Folder1/abc.txt','w')`, `print("Hello!", file=f)`.